# Or "||" syntax clarification

Tags: c#

In C#, if I want to check to make sure that a value does not equal X or Y, I would write something like this:

```
if(x != 1 && x != 2)
{
     //dosomething
}
```

I want to see if there is a way to write that with OR instead of AND. Something like this (which doesn't work, but its what I am trying to do):

```
if(x != (1 || 2))
{
     //dosomething
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work because it is trying to evaluate `1 || 2` as its own statement. Does there exist a way to write that correctly?

Comment: [C# basics Tutorial Conditional Statements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_decision_making.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can always invert an AND into an OR:

```
if (!(x == 1 || x == 2))
{
   ...
}
```

You have to reverse all the conditions to do it though, as above. The process for doing so is described in [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) (thanks @RichardEverett!).

Comment: @RichardEverett Thank you, I knew there was a name for that but couldn't remember it!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
if(!(x == 1 || x == 2))
```

but honestly, I don't see the reason of doing so.

This statement `if(x != 1 && x != 2)` is far more clear and readable than the above and it does the same.

This `(x == 1 || x == 2)` evaluates to true if x is either 1 or 2. Hence taking the negation of this, you get that you want.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET oops correct ! I was looking at it and when I realized you hit your comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No, C# doesn't support such a construct presently.
The following is about as close as I could get it, but it's slow!

```
if (!new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(x)) { ... }
```

Comment: While a valid alternative, simple boolean logic means you can *always* invert such a condition into an OR based statement.